# What does serializing a java object do behind the scenes

Tags: java, serialization

I understand serialization as the process of converting a Java object into bits so that it can be transported over the network.

But in memory, are not Java objects by default stored as a sequence of bits? So what exactly does serialization do?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does everything described in the [Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html). It's far too broad a question to answer here.